# python appending issues, function keeps changing values of list

Tags: sorting, search, recursion, bubble-sort, tail-recursion

I was trying to visualize bubblesort by making an animated plot on some unsorted list, say `np.random.permutation(10)`

so naturally I would append the list every time it's altered within the bubblesort function until it's completely sorted. Here's the code

```
def bubblesort(A):
  instant = []

  for i in range(len(A)-1):
    lindex=0
    while lindex+1<len(A):
      if A[lindex]> A[lindex+1]:
        swap(A,lindex,lindex+1)
        lindex+=1
      else:
        lindex+=1   

      instant.append(A)
  return instant
```

The problem is though, `instant` only returns

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

which is obviously not right. What has gone wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is being operated on in-place, and `bubblesort` is returning a list of references to this array. Notice that if you check `A` now, it is also sorted.

Changing

```
  if A[lindex]> A[lindex+1]:
      swap(A,lindex,lindex+1)
```

to

```
  if A[lindex]> A[lindex+1]:
      A = A.copy()
      swap(A,lindex,lindex+1)
```

making a copy before changing anything, should show the progress of the sort.